# Input fields are repeating in preview page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, print-preview

I have three check boxes with two is auto selected and I am displaying the text field with a label which check box is selected.

But after clicking on preview from I am getting input field twice. I mean I am getting four text field instated of two.

There is some issue with my `ready script`.Would you help me out in this?

```js
<!--If any check box clicked then active this script-->

$(function() {
  $(".add_student_input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(".students_items").append('<div class="form-group row ' + this.id + '"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</label><div class="col-sm-8"><input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" class="form-control" /></div></div>');
    } else {
      $('.students_items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
    }
  });
  });

<!--end script -->
$(document).ready( function(){
     $checkbox=$(".add_student_input");
     $checkbox.each(function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
         if(isChecked) {
            $(".students_items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"><label>' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</label><input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" class="form-control" /></div>');
            } else {
                 //check false
                  $('.students_items').find('.' + this.id).remove();
            }
        });
     });

    /*form preview*/
function PrintPreview() {
        var toPrint = document.getElementById('open_in_preview');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
        popupWin.document.open();
 popupWin.document.write('<html><title>::Print Preview::</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css" media="screen"/></head><body>')
        popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
        popupWin.document.write('</body></html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="open_in_preview">
<input type="checkbox" name="a"  id="class_1" class="add_student_input" data-type="text"  checked><label for="class_1">number1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="b"  id="class_2" class="add_student_input" data-type="text" checked><label class="class_2">number2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="c"  id="class_3" class="add_student_input" data-type="text"><label class="class_3">number3</label>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PrintPreview();">Preview form</a>
<span class="students_items"></span>
</body>
```

I am getting output like this.

[image]

Comment: aint you missing the url in `window.open('', '_blank')`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, What's wrong with it?

Comment: take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, As per my knowledge, If I used window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100"); then it will display the new browser  window  and If I used window.open('', '_blank') the it will display the new tab.

Comment: because you do a loop for the checkbox, so if there is more than 1 checkbox is checked, you will append the same amount of input onto your html onload, you need to clear the input 1st b4 append again

Comment: @Se0ng11, Can you help me out with some code?

Comment: hmmm, i dont see any issue here, have a look on the sample that i create, https://plnkr.co/edit/wnGWwcgAySrjfNQwqX3J?p=preview

Comment: I am getting blank preview page.

Comment: i update another 1, https://plnkr.co/edit/wnGWwcgAySrjfNQwqX3J?p=preview, the body id

Comment: @Se0ng11, I added whole code. I think you haven't added the preview script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154290/discussion-between-se0ng11-and-narendra-verma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as comment, why the script putting at the below of your page will cause multiple input, as when onload, it will run document ready and append again based on the checkbox, so to solve the issue, put `empty()` onto it will "reset" the input before append with a new 1

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
        $checkbox=$(".add_student_input"); 
        $(".students_items").empty(); //add this to clear it
        $checkbox.each(function(){ 
            var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked"); 
            if(isChecked) { 
                $(".students_items").append('<div class="' + this.id + '"><label>' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</label><input type="' + $(this).data('type') + '" name="input[]" placeholder="' + $(this).next('label').text() + '" class="form-control" /></div>'); 
            } else { 
            //check false 
                $('.students_items').find('.' + this.id).remove(); 
            } 
    }); 
});
```

update with another question by OP
please look at the plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/wnGWwcgAySrjfNQwqX3J?p=preview

the issue here is not related to `empty()`, it is how it behave on `DOM` ready(but i remove it as your question is different now), I had enhance your script so that it take only the needed tag, and also combine the script to make it clearer, please have a look, so in order to really read the checked behavior in the html, we need to add

```
this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

this will force the `checked` is being render in the html, and also
`$(function(){})` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: Your code is working but If I will use $(".students_items").empty(); then It is also clearing the all check box which I am selecting.

Comment: not really sure what you actually refer to, as `.students_items` is only `span`, hence, empty the `span` suppose won't clear any checkbox due to the checkbox is not within `.students_items`

Comment: I added one more script in the question. Please check it. If I select the third check box then text field auto display and clicked on preview then it is displaying only first and second text field. because of "students_items"

Comment: hi @NarendraVerma, is better to modify the plnkr that i previously attach to ease the look of your script and put in your question

Comment: @NarendraVerma, updated with new answer for your new question

Comment: Thank you very much @Se0ng11, It's working for me perfectly.Thanks for your information. Upvote from my side.